# Git pre-commit to include TFS item number

Tags: git, tfs

I'd like take advantage of pre-commit hook to include TFS/VSTS item number. That number can go from 1 to 5 digits and commit messages need to look like this `#12345: some commit message`, with TFS item number explicitly being at the beginning. What would that look like?

Thanks!

---

TFS: Team Foundation Server
VSTS: Visual Studio Team Editions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing the following inside `prepare-commit-msg`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $(cat "$1") =~ ^\#[0-9]{1,5}:.+ ]]; then
    echo "Your commit message is valid."
else
    echo "Your commit message have to be in format '#12345: Message'"
    exit 1
fi
```

This prevents me from committing anything without having the item number at the beginning. Sadly, Visual Studio does not support client-side hooks so it's only doable if you're using tools like TortoiseGit or SourceTree, or plain old bash.

Comment: Please mark the reply as answer for this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `prepare-commit-msg` git hook.
The files is under `/.git/hooks/` folder of your local git repository.

Edit the `prepare-commit-msg.sample` file , add this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ITEM=1234

echo "#($ITEM):`cat $1`" > "$1"
```

Then delete .sample file extension to make this file start to work.

You could write a method to generate the $`ITEM` value according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it pointed me in the right direction, see my own answer.

Comment: Please mark the reply as answer for this issue. Thanks!